# UITableView heightForHeaderInSection not working

Tags: ios, uitableview

I have a simple UITableView ([sample project here](http://cl.ly/WGMA)) but the section headers do not respect the height I'm setting in the `heightForHeaderInSection`

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return 40;
}
```

The table view looks like this. The 1 section header has a correct height but not the other ones.

[image]

When I inspect the view with the Reveal app, it seems that there is a kind of footer after the last cell in the section.

[image]

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Have checked delegate method is calling ?

Comment: yes the ```heightForHeaderInSection``` is called

Comment: @Jan Your tableview style is group or plain? i think it is because your style is group.

Comment: It's a grouped table view

Comment: Make it Plain if you don't want group else you should add `heightForFooter` delegate and `return 0`.

Comment: in plain tableview your demo code is perfectly work if you dont need group tableview so change only grouptableview to plain tableview and then try your code is perfectly work on that .

Answer (score 26, accepted):

What seems to work is this

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForFooterInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    return 0.0001f; // 0.0f does not work
}
```

or even better, in `loadView`

```
self.tableView.sectionFooterHeight = 0.0f;
```

Comment: seems like a bug. There are other answers to this problem with the same solution.

Comment: 2019 and still an issue. +1 for `sectionFooterHeight = 0`, this seems to be the cleanest solution.

Comment: 2020 and still an issue

Comment: 2021 and still an issue. in iOS10.

Answer (score 8):

**Swift**:

Swift version of approved answer:

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForFooterInSection section: Int) -> CGFloat {
    return CGFloat.leastNonzeroMagnitude
}
```

Comment: combining this answer this with the post below, I use `tableView.sectionFooterHeight = CGFloat.leastNonzeroMagnitude`

Answer (score -3):

Guessing into the blue and from your inside with the Reveal App try setting the footer to height 0.

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForFooterInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    return 0;
}
```

According to the docs:

> **Special Considerations** 
>   Prior to iOS 5.0, table views would
>   automatically resize the heights of footers to 0 for sections where
>   tableView:viewForFooterInSection: returned a nil view. In iOS 5.0 and
>   later, you must return the actual height for each section footer in
>   this method.

Comment: Returning ```0``` in ```heightForFooterInSection``` does not work. I tried also returning ```nil``` in ```viewForFooterInSection```

Comment: @Jan: This seems to be both a hack and the solution :-(